# how structure a python3/tkinter project

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm developing a small application using tkinter and PAGE 4.7 for design UI.
I had designed my interface and generated python source code. I got two files:

- gm_ui_support.py: here declare tk variables
- gm_ui.py : here declare widget for UI

I'm wondering how this files are supposed to be use, one of my goals is to be able to change the UI as many times as I need recreating this files, so if I put my code inside any of this files will be overwritten each time.

So, my question is:

- Where I have to put my own code? I have to extend gm_ui_support? I have to create a 3th class? I do directly at gm_ui_support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the lack of answer I'm going to explain my solution:

It seems that is not possible to keep both files unmodified, so I edit `gm_ui_support.py` (declaration of tk variables and events callback). Each time I make a change that implies `gm_ui_support.py` I copy changes manually.

To minimize changes on gm_ui_support I create a new file called `gm_control.py` where I keep a status dict with all variables (logical and visual) and have all available actions.

Changes on gm_ui_support.py:

- I create a generic function (sync_control) that fills my tk variables using a dict
- At initialize time it creates my class and invoke sync_control (to get default values defined in control)
- On each callback I get extract parameter from event and invoke logical action on control class (that changes state dict), after call to sync_control to show changes.

Sample:

gm_ui_support.py

```
 def sync_control():
    for k in current_gm_control.state:
        gv = 'var_'+k
        if  gv in globals():
            #print ('********** found '+gv)
            if type(current_gm_control.state[k]) is list:
                full="("
                for v in current_gm_state.state[k]:
                    if len(full)>1: full=full+','
                    full=full+"'"+v+"'"
                full=full+")"
                eval("%s.set(%s)" % (gv, full))
            else:
                eval("%s.set('%s')" % (gv, current_gm_state.state[k]))
        else:
            pass

def set_Tk_var():
   global current_gm_state
   current_gm_control=gm_control.GM_Control()

   global var_username
   var_username = StringVar()
   ...
   sync_control()
   ...

def on_select_project(event):
   w = event.widget
   index = int(w.curselection()[0])
   value = w.get(index)
   current_gm_control.select_project(value)
   sync_state()
...
```